# No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from the literal `7.5'

Tags: haskell

I am working on some code to calculate the price of something based on the type of item and how many are being bought. Below is what I have right now

```
calcPrice :: String -> Integer -> Integer
calcPrice tickType num
  | tickType=="Child" = (7.5 * num)
  | tickType=="Adult" = (12.5 * num)
  | tickType=="Senior" = (8 * num)
  | otherwise = 0

main = do  
  putStrLn "Please enter the type of ticket and amoount needed"
  ticketType <- getLine
  ticketNum <- getLine
  let x = read ticketNum :: Integer
  print(calcPrice ticketType x)
```

When I run this program and enter "Adult 5" it should print "62.5". When I run this program, I get an error saying "main.hs:4:25: error: * No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from the literal `7.5" If I change 7.5 to just 7, it moves to the next line for 12.5. This number needs to be how they are though.

I must be missing something dumb, because I'm not really sure how else to specify the number that the number of tickets will be multiplied by. I have tried fromIntegral() and fromInteger() on both the number 7.5 and num, but evidently it's not supposed to be used that way. How should I format these numbers so that the program can just multiply them normally?

Comment: 62.5 is not an integer number, so it does not fir into an `Integer`. Maybe you want to use `Double`for the result type (and `fromIntegral` to convert integers to doubles).

Comment: @chi Isn't using `Double`s for money kinda really bad?

Comment: Another solution is to simply go by cents instead of dollars, then you have integers everywhere and no loss of information, without needing to use a specialized type or rationals. If this is production code and not a toy example, you could make it explicit by using a type synonym (`type Cents = Integer`).

Comment: ＠MikaelF but the interest rates cannot be integers

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, but it might be good enough for the OP. This seems to be a beginner's exercise, not something to be used in production.

Answer (score 2):

`Data.Fixed` module, I think, is a good alternative to represent money. As for currencies, resolution of `0.01` is usually enough. So `Fixed E2` or the type synonym `Centi` is the choice. Since `Fixed a` is also instances of `Num`, `Fractional`, `Real`, etc, all the arithmetical calculations are available to the data type of `Fixed a`, and you can also use `fromIntegral` or `fromInteger` to convert an integer into a `Fixed a` number.

```hs
calcPrice :: String -> Int -> Fixed E2    -- Fixed E2 can be replaced by Centi
calcPrice tickType num
  | tickType=="Child" = (7.5 * fromIntegral num)
  | tickType=="Adult" = (12.5 * fromIntegral num)
  | tickType=="Senior" = (8 * fromIntegral num)
  | otherwise = 0
```

In the code above, `Fixed E2` represents a number that has resolution of `0.01`. For more information about `Data.Fixed`, you can see the [doc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html).

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, there's also `Data.Money` but that looks like overkill for what OP is doing

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you want to use `fromInteger` or `fromIntegral` on `num` to get it to multiply with the floating point numbers, but then the result of that is also a floating point number which you'll need to truncate or round in order to get back to an `Integer`:

```
ceiling $ 7.5 * (fromInteger 7)
```

(Initially I tired to use `toInteger` on the result instead of rounding, then figured out my mistake, so you're not the only one doing silly things :) )

As Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica mentioned in the comments, if this is production code you really don't want to be using floating point numbers to represent money, so I'd suggest trying a different route if that's the case.